# Which Ubuntu for ARM cpu do I need

Tags: server, files, arm, distro-recommendation

I'm planning on buying a single board computer that I would like to install Ubuntu server on. The problem is that I don't know which file I should download. I've taken a look at this page: www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm. Does that mean that I can only use Ubuntu server for ARM with those types of cpu's?

Comment: What is the problem to install Ubuntu Server if you "would like to install Ubuntu server on"?

Comment: I need to know which file (ubuntu server) I should for a banana pi.

Comment: What CPU is there?

Comment: See http://forum.lemaker.org/thread-972-1-1.html

Comment: http://forum.lemaker.org/thread-3007-1-1.html

Comment: http://www.armbian.com/banana-pi/

Comment: So I can't simply get it from the url from my first post?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately unlike the x86 world the arm world doesn't have a common "platform".

PCs all boot in the same way (well one of two ways since we have UEFI), they have crucial system hardware like timers in the same place. They all have the registers used to enumerate the PCI bus(es) in the same place. They have a BIOS that passes further details of the hardware to the OS.

Arm boards don't, each SoC is very different and the boards they are installed on are often different too. At a minimum you tend to need a board-specific bootloader and "dtb". Sometimes you also need a board-specific kernel, especially if you want full functionality.

What tends to end up happening is that only a small selection of hardware is officially supported by the distro, then the community around each given board puts together unofficial images for their boards.

The exception to this is arm server hardware. The arm server folks have adapted UEFI and ACPI to arm, providing a more PC like experience.

Comment: I see. So I guess it would be best to Just take a distro image from the developers' website.